# gs 9.22 on Linux doesn't render embedded fonts in pdf generated on Mac

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to render [this pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1txro8ol6Wbn-K0qrbrOne2EtqX-h_JLI/view) on Linux, but the produced png shows missing font blocks.

```
gs -sDEVICE=png16m -o test.png AGREE\ II\ lijst.pdf
```

[image]

The pdf was generated on a Mac (using its `print to pdf` feature), and contains embedded fonts:

```
$> pdffonts AGREE\ II\ lijst.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
EFPVPD+ArialMT                       TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      12  0
RFRCNT+TimesNewRomanPSMT             TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      10  0
FLZUKV+Arial-BoldMT                  TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      11  0
VQHCHW+Arial-ItalicMT                TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      13  0
```

`evince` and `qpdfview` show the pdf just fine, but printing fails, probably because my computer uses the same ghostscript to render the pdf to bitmap.

Help would be highly appreciated.

```
$> gs -help
GPL Ghostscript 9.22 (2017-10-04)
Copyright (C) 2017 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Usage: gs [switches] [file1.ps file2.ps ...]
Most frequently used switches: (you can use # in place of =)
 -dNOPAUSE           no pause after page   | -q       `quiet', fewer messages
 -g<width>x<height>  page size in pixels   | -r<res>  pixels/inch resolution
 -sDEVICE=<devname>  select device         | -dBATCH  exit after last file
 -sOutputFile=<file> select output file: - for stdout, |command for pipe,
                                         embed %d or %ld for page #
Input formats: PostScript PostScriptLevel1 PostScriptLevel2 PostScriptLevel3 PDF
Default output device: x11alpha
Available devices:
   alc1900 alc2000 alc4000 alc4100 alc8500 alc8600 alc9100 ap3250 atx23
   atx24 atx38 bbox bit bitcmyk bitrgb bitrgbtags bj10e bj10v bj10vh bj200
   bjc600 bjc800 bjc880j bjccmyk bjccolor bjcgray bjcmono bmp16 bmp16m
   ...
   plibk plibm png16 png16m png256 png48 pngalpha pnggray pngmono pngmonod
   pnm pnmraw ppm ppmraw pr1000 pr1000_4 pr150 pr201 ps2write psdcmyk
   psdcmykog psdrgb pwgraster pxlcolor pxlmono r4081 rinkj rpdl samsunggdi
   ...
   xpswrite
Search path:
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Init :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/lib :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts : /usr/share/fonts/Type1 : /usr/share/fonts
Ghostscript is also using fontconfig to search for font files
For more information, see /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/doc/Use.htm.
Please report bugs to bugs.ghostscript.com.
```

I even have the fonts installed on my computer:

```
$> fc-list : family | egrep -i arial\|times
Times New Roman
Times
Arial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghostscript 9.22 built from the tagged release source (available at the bottom of the table [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) currently) on Fedora 23, renders the file as expected for me.

So it seems likely that its not 'gs9.22 on Linux' its 'the build of Ghostscript 9.22 on my flavour of Linux, compiled by the package maintainer on the Linux distribution I'm using' which is most probably at fault.

There could be **many** reasons for this. Firstly the various distributions apply their own patches to the Ghostscript source tree. Secondly, the packagers insist on using system shared libraries, instead of the 3rd party library sources shipped with the Ghostscript source. We, the Ghostscript development team, **know** those work, because that's what we test. We can't test every possible version (and patch) of all the system libraries shipped with every flavour of Linux and you may have hit some kind of incompatbility (most likely with FreeType since its fonts).

Note that what you are seeing there are not 'missing font blocks' but missing **glyphs**. That's the /.notdef glyph which is used to render in place of a glyph when that glyph is not present in the font. You haven't given the back channel output from Ghostscript when rendering the file, if the fonts were missing then there would be some warnings about that.

I would suggest that you fetch the Ghostscript source, either the tarball from the link above, or use Git and get the latest sources. Build it yourself (you will need gcc, make and autotools installed) and test that. If that doesn't work, then please file a bug report [here](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/) Please be sure to describe how you built Ghostscript, specify the command line you used, and attach the offending file to the bug report.

There is a pre-built Linux binary at the same location, and you could try that, but there's a reasonable chance that it simply won't work on your Linux.

By the way, having the fonts available on your system won't help at all, because the fonts in the PDF file have been subset and re-encoded. There's essentially no way to use the system fonts to replace the ones embedded in the PDF file, the interpreter **must** use the embedded fonts.

Comment: Ok *thanks*. I just downloaded gs-922-linux-x86_64 and just replacing my system ([Void linux](voidlinux.eu)) binary with that one made the issue disappear!
I'll try to see what's wrong with the distro ghostscript, and fix it there.

Comment: usr2564301: 'we' in this case is the Ghostscript development team. Bart Van Deenen: Thanks for letting me know that the pre-built binary is good, that's a relief :-) Lucky that it worked for you. Figuring out what's wrong with the distribution could be difficult, I'd be inclined to report it to the package maintainer and let them liaise with us.

Comment: One of my colleagues suggested this could be the problem http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=ead0b5bee31a6e2756749a5c8fb6508e49b64703 The bug is exposed by a change in FreeType, so using a different (newer) version of FreeTtype than the one supplied (and tested) with 9.22 would exhibit the problem. The commit there resolves the problem with newer versions of FreeType, so the 9.23 release imminent) won't suffer from this. As noted above, we test with the code we ship, so using shared system libraries can break things.

Comment: Void Linux has a rolling release system, so it tends to break stuff earlier :-). The freetype I have is 2.9_2. Thanks for your *invaluable* help